# Why won't VSync turn off in fullscreen in DirectX11?

Tags: directx-11, vsync

I have a weird issue in our engine in DirectX11. When I run our game windowed, I can enable or disable VSync just fine. However, when the game's resolution is the same as the screen resolution, VSync is somehow always on. This happens both in Exclusive Fullscreen and in Borderless Window Fullscreen.

So for example, my monitor is 1920*1200. If I run in DirectX11 in Borderless Window Fullscreen on 1920*1200, I *always* get 60fps (so vsync is apparently on). If I run on 1920*1080, I can turn off vsync and get other framerates (for example 250fps, so vsync really is turned off).

I've seen this on more than one computer, but I don't know whether it happens on all computers.

Our engine also supports DirectX9 and OpenGL and the problem doesn't happen there: I can turn VSync on and off just fine there, regardless of resolution.

I turn VSync on and off by calling either of these, respectively:

```
swapChain->Present(1, 0); //on
swapChain->Present(0, 0); //off
```

I create the swapChain like this:

```
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC1 swapChainDesc = {0};
swapChainDesc.Width = windowWidth;
swapChainDesc.Height = windowHeight;
swapChainDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
swapChainDesc.Stereo = false;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2;
swapChainDesc.Scaling = DXGI_SCALING_STRETCH;
swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_FLIP_SEQUENTIAL;
swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;
SDL_SysWMinfo& windowInfo = getWindowInfo();
IDXGISwapChain1* swapChain = nullptr;
dxgiFactory->CreateSwapChainForHwnd(device, windowInfo .info.win.window, &swapChainDesc, nullptr, nullptr, &swapChain);
```

What am I doing wrong here? Why does turning VSync off only work when the game isn't covering the entire screen?

Comment: What OS are you using (including build number)?

Comment: We've seen this on more than one computer with different versions, but not on all computers we use. One computer that has this issue is Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 18363) with an AMD Radeon RX 5600 XT, driver version 20.10.17.01. For another computer I don't know the build numbers, but it's a very old Windows 10 update with an Nvidia Geforce 970.

Comment: Same here. In Borderless window fullscreen, the game is capped at the monitor refresh rate, even if vsync is not enabled.

Comment: Unfortunately we haven't made any progress on this one yet. Please share if you do encounter a solution,